# Is calling CMD from vb.net sandboxed?

Tags: vb.net, windows, batch-file, cmd, process

I've been trying to call cmd in order to run a command and get the output from it - specifically the "query user /server:servername" command, and have found lots of posts discussing how to run it. When I run it though, it seems to work for most commands (ipconfig, ping, tracert) but not my query user command. Interestingly, the code below seems to be ok for most commands but not this one.

```
Process.Start("cmd", "/c query user /server:PCNAME")
```

I also tried creating a batch file and running that.

```
Dim currentdir As String = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory
    Dim server As String = txt_target_server.Text
    Dim cmdline As String = "query user /server:" & server & " > tmpidlvw.txt"
    IO.File.WriteAllText("tempbat.bat", "@echo off" & vbNewLine & cmdline)
    Process.Start("tempbat.bat")

    Dim currentreader As StreamReader
    Dim currentfile As String = currentdir & "\tmpidlvw.txt"
    If System.IO.File.Exists(currentfile) Then
        currentreader = New StreamReader(currentfile)
        Dim usercount As Integer = 0
        Dim userarray(100) As String
        Do While Not currentreader.EndOfStream
            Dim tempstring As String = currentreader.ReadLine
            MsgBox(tempstring)
            userarray(usercount) = tempstring
            usercount += 1
        Loop
        currentreader.Close()
        For count As Integer = 1 To usercount
            MsgBox(userarray(count))
        Next
    Else
        MsgBox(currentfile)
    End If
```

This also fails. I found that the batch file it creates works fine if I run it normally (the code generates it ok). I've isolated it to that the process.start(cmd.exe) doesn't seem to run the same as normal cmd.
for Example, if i run process.start(cmd.exe) and then do the following

```
cd c:\windows\system32
dir | findstr query
```

I get the following

```
14/07/09 02:14 AM            66,048 driverquery.exe
14/07/09 02:15 AM           395,776 dsquery.dll
08/07/15 10:48 PM         1,549,312 tquery.dll
```

If I run the exact same command from a normal command prompt, the output is below.

```
14/07/09 02:39 AM            96,256 driverquery.exe
14/07/09 02:40 AM           429,056 dsquery.dll
21/11/10 04:24 AM            16,384 query.exe
08/07/15 10:48 PM         2,315,776 tquery.dll
```

I believe this is why it fails - the cmd called does not "see" the same directory as a normal command prompt and cannot see the query.exe file.

Does anyone know what I can do to get this to work? I've verified this happens if I run my code on another machine, and have turned off vmware debugging, antivirus, autosandbox etc.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-4

Comment: @MrGadget I also tried using this method and got the same result - "query" is not recognized as a valid internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: Provide the full path?

Comment: @MrGadget If you mean doing    process.start(c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe) then I tried that - or do you mean in the cmd command itself?

Comment: full path to query.exe